# What kind of board does an XMC network card fit in?

Tags: motherboard, network-adapter, computer-building

I'm looking at 10GbE network cards, and most of what I find are XMC format, like the [XPort3300](http://www.xes-inc.com/products/view/xport3300/) (just an example). I'm trying to understand how these cards fit on a board. I'm very new to low-level hardware, so it's very confusing for me.

Will these kinds of cards fit on a standard motherboard, like in a desktop PC? Do they require something specific?

If it helps, I'm more interested in Intel, rack-mounted systems.

Comment: Wikipedia claims, but does not cite, that "A PCI Mezzanine Card or PMC is a printed circuit board manufactured to the IEEE P1386.1 standard. This standard combines the electrical characteristics of the PCI bus with the mechanical dimensions of the Common Mezzanine Card or CMC format (IEEE 1386 standard)." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Mezzanine_Card It also expands XMC as Switched Mezzanine Card. *Based on this* limited information, it's a specific type of bus and card form factor, so you would need a backplane/motherboard that actually supports XMC specifically.

Answer (score 0):

They won't fit normally, so cards like this are put into standard motherboard computers via adapters into the PCI-E slot.
[Link](http://www.cotsjournalonline.com/img/archive_images/cots0710/cots0710_sd_child_f2.jpg).

I couldn't tell you the cost of the adapter, however.

Comment: What kind of boards are these cards normally put in?

Comment: Generally, they aren't put into the motherboards directly at all, but accompany a main card and are a 'daughter' card onto something else. The only XMC boards I ever worked with were daughter cards, so I can't provide much more information. The application for them was military based for General Dynamics, as I'm assuming most uses are.