# How do you use an XMC network card?

Tags: networking, motherboard, computer-building

In relation to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/927246/what-kind-of-board-does-an-xmc-network-card-fit-in/927254?noredirect=1#comment1254822_927254), how exactly does an XMC card attach to another card? I'm trying to build a machine for a work project and I don't know a lot about hardware. I understand that XMC cards aren't directly put into a motherboard, that they have to be a 'daughter' card, but I don't understand how that is supposed to work.

As a follow up: how can I tell which XMC cards are compatible with non-XMC?